# Python Get metadata from files in directory

Tags: python

I wouldlike to get some data from files in same directory :

```
 directory = filedialog.askdirectory() + '/'
 for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     print(filename) # name
```

How to get size, date (modify file) and type of file ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `subprocess` module from the standard library:

```
import subprocess

filename = 'subpr.py'
p = subprocess.run(['ls', '-la', 'grep', filename], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(p.stdout)
```

#### output

```
permissions refs  user       status  size datetime_created filename  # <- headers not part of the output
-rw-rw-rw-  1 reblochonmasque  staff  1013 Jun 28 18:43 subpr.py
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `os.stat` to get a structure with various fields, including those you're looking for.

`print(os.stat(os.path.join(directory, filename)))`